# Example for a block device on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, device

I'm playing with the Posix `stat()` function on Linux, macOS and Windows and want to try it out with different devices, to see the outcome. Support for certain types, e.g. sockets and FIFOs is non-existent on Windows, but I'd like to check at least block and character devices. I found `AUX` (and a few others like that) to be character devices, however I cannot find any block device that's available on Windows by default. Can someone please suggest an example?

Comment: COM1(represents RS-232) is a character device.  \\.\X: represents dis X, which is a block device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows, not being a POSIX OS, does not support `stat`. It has a similar function, [`_stat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/stat-functions), which attempts to *emulate* the functionality.

However, even though Windows does have a notion of a block device, there is no `S_IFBLK` (block device) flag in the Windows implementation; if you look in `stat.h` you'll see that only the following mode flags are supported:

```
#define _S_IFMT   0xF000 // File type mask
#define _S_IFDIR  0x4000 // Directory
#define _S_IFCHR  0x2000 // Character special
#define _S_IFIFO  0x1000 // Pipe
#define _S_IFREG  0x8000 // Regular
#define _S_IREAD  0x0100 // Read permission, owner
#define _S_IWRITE 0x0080 // Write permission, owner
#define _S_IEXEC  0x0040 // Execute/search permission, owner
```

From this it can be concluded that what you're asking is impossible.

Indeed, `_stat("C:")` fails with `ENOENT` and `_stat("\\\\.\\C:")` fails with `EINVAL`.

Comment: Yes, good point about the missing flag and hence unsupported device. From the list I see that FIFOs (on Win: pipes) are supported, however. Do you perhaps have an example of a pipe that always exists on the system?

Comment: Sure, you can stat the eventlog pipe with `_stat("\\\\.\\pipe\\eventlog")`

Comment: The common `stat` implementations on Windows are limited to filesystems. They're implemented by opening a handle and calling `GetFileInformationByHandle` or the newer `GetFileInformationByHandleEx`, which ultimately queries filesystem information via `NtQueryVolumeInformationFile` (e.g. for `FileFsVolumeInformation`) and `NtQueryInformationFile` (e.g. for `FileAllInformation`). Most non-filesystem devices do not support the queried information classes, so `stat` will fail. Notably "\\.\PIPE" (aka "\Device\NamedPipe" in native NT code) is a rudimentary filesystem device.

Comment: Also, implementations that call `GetInformationByHandle` don't have the proper `ChangeTime` from the native `FileBasicInformation` for `st_ctime`, so they substitute the file's `CreationTime` (i.e. `st_birthtime` on some Unix systems). Also, they set `st_dev` as the `VolumeSerialNumber`, but Windows allows this to be 0. And they set `st_ino` from the file's `IndexNumber`, which Windows also allows to be 0. Both are 0 for a mounted WebDAV drive. POSIX code ported to Windows may naively assume that (`st_dev`, `st_ino`) uniquely identifies a file because POSIX guarantees this.